# UI locking up when using AlamoFire downloadProgress

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire

I'm trying to create a download progress bar and show an alert at the same time when a download is completing.

For this task, I'm using AlamoFire with SwiftUI since it makes downloading easy.
However, when I track the progress using a ProgressView with a Published variable, the entire UI locks up and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I tried adding the downloadProgress to a separate DispatchQueue, but I still have to update the UI from the main thread otherwise Xcode will complain.

How to test the attached example code:

- Click "Start download"
- Wait for the ProgressView to move a bit
- Click the "Show alert" button
- Try closing the alert, it won't close.

I would appreciate any help.

import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                showAlert.toggle()
            }
            
            Button("Start download") {
                viewModel.startDownload()
            }
            
            if viewModel.showProgressView {
                ProgressView("Downloading…", value: viewModel.downloadProgress, total: 1.0)
                    .progressViewStyle(.linear)
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Text"),
                dismissButton: .cancel()
            )
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentDownload: DownloadRequest? = nil
    @Published var downloadProgress: Double = 0.0
    @Published var showProgressView: Bool = false
    
    func startDownload() {
        print("Function called!")
        
        showProgressView.toggle()
        
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "alamofire", qos: .utility)
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

        AF.download("https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin", to: destination)
            .downloadProgress(queue: queue) { progress in
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.downloadProgress = progress.fractionCompleted
                }
            }
            .response { response in
                print(response)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are effectively spamming the UI thread with updates, since alamofire calls the closure provided to `downloadProgress` very often (look at the console prints). You need to stagger the updates from AF progress a bit so that the button press to dismiss the alert can register (in Combine this would be known as debounce). What I've done here is added a little time counter so that it only updates the progress every `1` second. The time between those updates keeps the UI thread free to respond to taps etc.

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Alert") {
                showAlert.toggle()
            }
            
            Button("Start download") {
                viewModel.startDownload()
            }
            
            if viewModel.showProgressView {
                ProgressView("Downloading…", value: viewModel.downloadProgress, total: 1.0)
                    .progressViewStyle(.linear)
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Text"),
                dismissButton: .cancel()
            )
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentDownload: DownloadRequest? = nil
    @Published var downloadProgress: Double = 0.0
    @Published var showProgressView: Bool = false
    
    func startDownload() {
        print("Function called!")
        
        showProgressView.toggle()
        
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "net", qos: .userInitiated)
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
        var last = Date()
        AF.download("https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin", to: destination)
            .downloadProgress(queue:queue) { progress in
                print(progress.fractionCompleted)
                if Date().timeIntervalSince(last) > 1 {
                    last = Date()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.downloadProgress = progress.fractionCompleted
                    }
                }
            }
            .response { response in
//                print(response)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```